# Statistics with Python

Tags: python, beginner, statistics

> Write a program to determine the mean, median, and standard deviation of a list of numbers
>   Count the duplicate numbers in the code, listing any that occur more than once with the number of times it occurs.

My implementation:

```
import math

def mean(input):
  return sum(input) / float(len(input))

def median(input):
  sorted_input = sorted(input)
  length = len(input)
  if length < 1:
    return None
  if length % 2 == 0:
    return (sorted_input[length / 2] + sorted_input[length / 2 - 1]) / float(2)
  else:
    return sorted_input[length / 2]

def duplicate_counts(input):
  distinct_input = set(input)
  for distinct in set(input):
    count = input.count(distinct)
    if (count > 1):
      print("{} occurs {} times".format(distinct, count))


def standard_deviation(input):
  return math.sqrt(mean([(x - mean(input)) ** 2 for x in input]))

def main():
  #sample run/test
  the_list = [3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 9, 2, 1, 6, 9, 6]
  print("The mean is: {}".format(mean(the_list)))
  print("The median is: {}".format(median(the_list)))
  print("The standard deviation is: {}".format(standard_deviation(the_list)))
  duplicate_counts(the_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Sample output:

> ```
> The mean is: 5.23529411765  
> The median is: 6  
> The standard deviation is: 2.64640514805  
> 2 occurs 3 times  
> 3 occurs 2 times  
> 6 occurs 3 times  
> 7 occurs 2 times  
> 9 occurs 3 times
> ```

Simple exercise I decided to do with Python for practice and to test/try all the excellent feedback I received on my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105561/producing-and-comparing-maximum-sub-array-sum-algorithms) [two](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107343/getting-funky-with-pi) questions. There may be built in functions for these, and feel free to mention them, but for the sake of practice I implemented them this way.

Comment: Are you using Python2 or 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A variable name `input` is confusing. After all, `input` is a Python built-in.
- `standard_deviation` calls `mean` too many times (add a debug printout to `mean` to see). Better do

  ```
  def standard_deviation(input):
      input_mean = mean(input)
      return math.sqrt(mean([(x - input_mean) ** 2 for x in input]))
  ```
- Median can be calculated in \$ O(\log n)\$. Sorting a list in \$O(n \log n)\$ just for a median is an overkill.

Comment: I may be missing something (I probably am) but, in your second tip, it seems to me that all you are doing is storing one of the mean calls in a variable. Was tip a tip for increasing readability?

Comment: Just to clarify, for calculating the median, you're suggesting I create a better performing sorting algorithm?

Comment: @Legato Not _sorting_, but equal partitioning. To find a median you don't need partitions to be sorted.

Comment: @SirPython the storage into a variable seems mainly to avoid computing the mean for each element in the input list, thus saving on CPU.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Ah, that makes perfect sense! Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Can you give an example of this \$O(\log{n})\$ algorithm?
A search for 'equal partitioning' gives answers to things I don't think you mean (I could be wrong).
Where [Median Algorithm in O(log n)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3632310/2044866) says it's possible in less than \$O(n)\$,
but douse not say it's either possible or impossible for all unsorted lists in \$O(\log{n})\$.

Answer (score 2):

In `mean`, you're wrapping the result of `len` in a float. I'm guessing this is because of Python 2's odd division that will always return an int and not a float.

```
>>> 12/5
2
```

In Python 3.x this is no longer an issue as it will return proper float values, and you can get this in Python 2 as well, by using `from __future__ import division`. `from __future__` is a way of importing new additions in Python 3 that were added to 2 but not in a way that overrides the old functionality. By importing this, division returns floats in Python 2 as well:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 12/5
2.4
```

Also I notice you use `float` later on the literal value 2. But you could just use 2.0 and get the same effect even if you don't do the import.

```
>>> 12/5.0
2.4
```

Should `median` really return `None` for input of length 0? Shouldn't that `raise ValueError` rather than silently return a non result?

Also you should indent by 4 spaces rather than 2. That's the commonly accepted Python style, and since it affects flow people could easily misread your code this way.